Firebase Remote Config A/B Experiment Targeting based on event
I have a React Native app. I'm doing A/B testing via Firebase A/B Testing and Remote Config.
I want to run an A/B test for new users during the registration flow, when a particular event is triggered. Let's call it EventA.
I'm fetching the remote config on app launch. I have a remote config value which controls the app behaviour based on the remote config value.
Later when a user triggers EventA, I want it to trigger the A/B test. I want it to be a 50/50 split of those who triggered the event i.e. 50% of users who triggered the event get "behaviour A" and 50% get "behaviour B".
However for that to be an accurate test, I would need to configure ONLY those users in the Target properties in the Firebase console A/B test settings. That doesn't seem possible to me.
I can't use Google Analytics User Audience because that can take up to 48 hours for the data to get across, so useless in this case. It needs to be instant.
If I target ALL app users and do a 50/50 split, then it won't be a true A/B test because not all users are going to trigger the event and be included in the test. Therefore those who DO trigger the event, and are included in the test, it won't be a true 50/50 split.
Is there some way to target ONLY those users who triggered EventA and then do a re-retch of the remote config to get their setting, but only AFTER they've triggered the event?

You should be start using "Activation event". This event is being a trigger to entry the AB test for users. Users, who triggers the activation event they will be included in measurement result and they will receive 50/50 split. If they don't trigger the activation event, they are not in AB test.
The activation event can be set in AB test detail in the section after "Targeting" section. See here on image: 
Even though the values are fetched on the mobile app start, the values are activated after activation event has been triggered (this logic is upon Firebase SDK and is not documented properly).
